Conditionally include entries in AdditionalIncludeDirectories
Is it possible to include entries for AdditionalIncludeDirectories based on a condition? I know we can add it based on configuation and platform, but more so, can we add a certain path in a certain way if run in local vs on teamcity servers?
This is basically needed because the way some folders are packaged in local vs on the server are different and we cannot modify them. If I have only one, I can either build on TC or on local. Not on both.
Example:
On local -> ..\..\..\lib_name\include
On server -> $(OutDir)\include
I want to say
if 'Local':
    ..\..\..\lib_name\include
else:
    $(OutDir)\include

Please suggest best options.

Yeah, you can do that with an environment variable. Set a TEAMCITY_BUILD or something like that on the server. Won't exist locally.
In the project file, check for this variable. If it’s set, use the server path, otherwise use the local path.
Something like:

On TeamCity: set TEAMCITY_BUILD=true
In .vcxproj add condition to check if TEAMCITY_BUILD exists. Use the right path based on that.

You can control the build based on where it’s running without changing stuff every time.
